# Using wget to download only the first depth of external links

Tags: backup, wget, download, mirror

I would like to get a copy of this page: http://databyte.ch/services/tony/index.html obviously this page is already a copy of the original source: http://www.tonyvanroon.com/oldwebsite/circ/circuits.htm

But there were some broken links. Now i have made a copy of the index page and corrected all the links to point to the wayback archive. Now nearly evereything is browseable. But now i would like to make a copy of the corrected page with wget. 
The problem now is: if wget follows the external links due to the -H parameter, it will also download files which are linked in the external page.

For example: 
On this page: https://web.archive.org/web/20130318175317if_/http://www.sentex.ca/~mec1995/circ/alt1.htm

there is a link to: 
https://web.archive.org/web/20130401212207if_/http://www.sentex.ca/~mec1995/circ/circuits.htm

These are different timestamps: 20130318175317if_ vs 20130401212207if_

Now the wheel gets spinning. Cause on the second index page there are links with many other timestamps and so on...

So what i would like to achieve is, that wget only downloads down to the first level:

databyte.ch -> All links which points to https://web.archive.org/web/20130318175317if_

And not more...

How can i achieve that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the depth parameter with wget:

> ```
>   -l depth
>   --level=depth
>       Specify recursion maximum depth level depth.
> ```

```
wget -r -l 1 -k -p -H --domains=web.archive.org http://databyte.ch/services/tony/index.html
```

Where -r sets recursive mode, -k converts links, -p download pre-requisites and -H spans hosts. Specifying --domains will only span to those hosts.

Comment: thanks for your answer :)